# undefine underscore in angular 2 cli project

Tags: angular

I ave angular2 prohject generated by cli. I want to import under module to use _.uniq(arr) function. But I refer to this library:

```
./../typings/globals/underscore/index.d.ts.
```

Here is a code of componet where I trying to use underscore:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Params, IndexService }   from '../services/index.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
var sizeof = require('object-sizeof');
var striptags = require('striptags');
// var _ = require("underscore.string");
var s = require("underscore.string");
import * as _ from 'underscore';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-analysis-content',
  templateUrl: './analysis-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./analysis-content.component.css']
})

    export class AnalysisContentComponent implements OnInit {
      countInfo: {};
      percents: number;
      countOfKeyword: number;
      microdataArray: [];

      constructor(private indexService: IndexService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

.....

```
  private checkTitleCohance(dom: any) {
    var el = this.createDOM(dom);
    var title = el.getElementsByTagName('title');
    var _title = title[0].innerText;
    var res = this.splitString(_title);
    var body = this.splitString(this.getContent(dom));
    var count = 0;
    _.unique(res);
```

Comment: Adjust systemjs.config(map: { 'underscore' : 'http://.....underscore.js' })

Comment: Where I need to write this config?

Comment: systemjs.config.js, there are some config object laying, so you need to add underscore into map property